# Root systems and subroot systems

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, lie-algebras, root-systems

Given the root system $E_{6}$ with basis $\alpha_{1},\dotsc,\alpha_{6}$. How would I find all subroot systems of $E_{6}$ (up to Weyl equivalence) where I can write the basis of each subroot system in terms of the roots $\alpha_{i}$?

Comment: You can use Borel-de Siebenthal theory to find the maximal subroot systems, then induct. I guess at some point you also have to consider maximal parabolic subroot systems as well.

Comment: @SamHopkins I assume this is the algorithm where you take one of the connected components of your Dynkin diagram extend by the most negative root and delete some subset of vertices of this component? It seems like quite a lengthy calculation and it seems to give a lot of subroot systems of the same type which I am not sure how to check are Weyl equivalent.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. I am not sure if there is a more efficient way. Probably this particular computation has been done before, though.

Comment: @SamHopkins Thanks for your help! Would you also possibly know how to find the most negative root for a given basis?

Comment: Have you looked in Carter's article on conjugacy classes in Weyl groups?  I doubt he explicitly describes exactly what you want, but his computations might be relevant.

Comment: @LSpice I have not, I will take a look. Thank you.

Comment: You can find the highest root using “Kostant’s game” as discussed here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/172033/25028

Comment: @PSHINH2 note that just extending by the lowest root won't get you all possibilities except for ADE diagrams for the others (BCFG) you need to also allow extending by the lowest short root (see the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3864501/which-root-systems-admit-a-proper-root-subsystem-with-full-span) )

Comment: For a full classification check out [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611904) paper by Oshima which goes through it pretty extensively.